# PHP YII framework searching by count

Tags: php, yii

I have two table called, `product` and `productComment`

Product Table Model

```
productID   userID    productName
```

ProductComment Table Model

```
userID    productID    Comment
```

I have two virtual field called `comment1` and `comment2`

when a user fills this field `comment1` as 2, and `comment2` as 5 for example.
I want to show count of product comment that match from 2 to 5. How can i do that?

Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `group` and `having` to your query criteria. You didn't show your relation definition, so depending on your column/relation names you need something along the lines of

```
$criteria->group = 't.productID';
$criteria->having = 'COUNT(comment.commentID) > '.((int)$this->comment1).
    ' AND COUNT(comment.commentID) < '.((int)$this->comment2);
```